# How to alert user before leaving webpage and run ajax function if user presses "ok"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this function that is supposed to ask the user if they are sure that they want to leave or refresh the website and if they say yes and leave the ajax function is executed. My problem is if the ajax function is alone the user is given no warning but if anything else is in the code the ajax function doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                return "";
                $.ajax({url: "checkout.php", type : 'post', data : { page_left: 1}});
            }
       </script>
```

Comment: Nothing after `return "";` will be executed. `return` statements should be last. Also, what does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Sorry, I removed the PHP tag. Okay but if the return statement is last then ajax gets executed no matter what. So I'm screwed.

Comment: Use a [confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)?

Comment: There is nothing that tells you if they select yes or no. What you want to do is not really possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
 if (window.confirm("Do you really want to leave?")) {
  $.ajax({url: "checkout.php", type : 'post', data : { page_left: 1}});
} } </script>
```

Check this will help